# Lightning Out fails to load due to app endpoint responding with relative url scripts

Tags: lightning-out

I am loading a component from an external page, but when it calls the `appname.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT` URL in the host org, it responds with a "scripts" field that contains only relative URLs, which causes the loading to fail.  It should be responding with absolute URLs in order to load the components.

Comment: please add more details and go through [Ask] first

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this by using *.lightning.force.com instead as the base URL.